# How can I make a delay in the test so that the page is fully loaded?

Tags: java, junit

I use [io.qameta.atlas](https://github.com/qameta/atlas), how do I make a delay after testing the first checkbox? Here's the test:

```
    @Test
public void produrtTest(){
    onSite().onMainPage().getButton().findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"-category-section\"]/div/ul/li[1]/label/span")).click();
    onSite().onMainPage().getButton().findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"- 
category-section\"]/div/ul/li[2]/label/span")).click();

   }
```

I used the `@Retry annotation(timeout = 20, polling = 5000)` to wait 20 seconds for the page to load, but there is no pause.

How to use the waitUntil () method is also unclear.

Answer (score 1):

At the very [front page](https://github.com/qameta/atlas) of the tool you are using there's this section:

> **Waiting for page loading.** There is a special shouldUrl(Matcher
> url) that waits on the condition for page’s current url and
> document.readyState flag.

```
@BaseUrl("http://www.base.url/search")
public interface SearchPage extends WebPage {

     @Description("Account button")
     @FindBy("//div[@class = 'account-button']")
     AtlasWebElement accountButton();
}

@BaseUrl("http://www.base.url/account")
public interface AccountPage extends WebPage {

     //elements for account page here
}
```

As well as

> **Waiting on a condition for a single element.** AtlasWebElement have two
> different extension methods for waiting.
>
> First - waitUntil(Matcher matcher) which waits with a configurable
> timeout and polling on some condition in a passed matcher, throwing
> java.lang.RuntimeException if condition has not been satisfied.
>
> Second - should(Matcher matcher) which waits the same way on a passed
> matcher, but throwing java.lang.AssertionError instead.

One of those should satisfy your need, depending on what you're waiting for (you did not specify).

Comment: I used onSite().onMainPage().getButton().waitUntil(DisplayedMatcher.displayed(), 10).findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"-category-section\"]/div/ul/li[1]/label/span")).click();